# Newbie - What are the pros & cons of using vim instead of gedit

Tags: command-line, gedit, vim

I am a bit confused as of advantages or disadvantages of using 'vim, versus gedit. I just find 'gedit' very practical.

Thks

Comment: In addition to the other answers I would add that vi/vim editors are very powerful with lots of features and if you know the shortcuts/codes then they can be a lot more efficient to use than more modern text editors like gedit. But if you never used them before then it can be a steep learning curve and it can seem very awkward to do anything (e.g. the source of all the "can't quit" vim memes). If you need a terminal editor and vim is too arcane for you then there are other options such as `nano`.

Comment: vim is more powerfull for massive actions. For example, if you want to comment all the lines of your file by adding a # in first caracter, you can do it very easilly with 1 command with vim. An other advange of vim is that you can find it in every linux system.

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of things in Linux we have a multitude of tools that can do the same but are for a different audience. When you have a server version and not a desktop gedit is not an option. You might not use a server version ever in your life but there is likely also someone else that will never use an Ubuntu desktop.

When you have trouble starting a desktop (for instance when your graphical driver bugs out) and you are left with a TTY login you basically are using the server part of Ubuntu. In that case you can still use an editor like `vim` or `vi` and not `gedit`.

The only downside to `vim` ... it has so so so many features and all of them linked to a keyboard shortcut it will take time to get proficient.

Answer (score 1):

They are, among text editors, completely different applications.
A main difference:
vim works at the     command line
gedit is a   gui        .

Some of the features offered by gedit are:

1. Full support for internationalized text (UTF-8)
2. Configurable syntax highlighting for various languages (C, C++, Java, HTML, XML, Python, Perl and many others)
3. Undo/Redo

On the other hand, Vim provides the following key features:

1. Vertically Split Windows
2. Vimdiff
3. Folding

**Related**:

1. [https://www.slant.co/versus/42/58/~vim_vs_gedit](https://www.slant.co/versus/42/58/%7Evim_vs_gedit)
2. https://stackshare.io/stackups/gedit-vs-vim

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I recently saw some information about split windows in Vim, will look into this.

Answer (score -1):

The permission side of thing is the real hell in Linux, you should **really** avoid using elevated GUI apps.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3071/407300) answer for more info

But on normal non-elevated apps, it's fine, otherwise you have nano in the CLI which is really easy to work with

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've heard of nano, will try it.